# Is the new deeper SkyDrive integration in Windows 8.1 suitable for syncing large files that have small changes applied to them often? (VM images)

Tags: sync, windows-8.1, onedrive

Is the new deeper SkyDrive integration in Windows 8.1 suitable for syncing large files that have small changes applied to them often?

I am thinking about VM images or TrueCrypt volumes.

This would obviously require delta sync. No one wants to upload the whole disk image when a few bytes change. SkyDrive did not support delta sync before. Does it support this scenario now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly doubt that it supports delta sync. However, according to their [FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/skydrive/upload-file-cant-faq#) you can't upload a file larger than 2GB to SkyDrive. Most VM images are probably going to be much larger than that.

UPDATE: Also, according to [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/skydrive-signin/skydrive-and-true-crypt/5cb4ac42-ac00-4c12-af30-fe92615d4f1a) in the SkyDrive forums, TrueCrypt does not work with SkyDrive. You could manually upload the TrueCrypt container whenever it changes, but that obviously is not ideal.